# Portable binary in RocksDB

Tags: c++, linker, rocksdb

I compile my code using the following set of flags

```
    LIBS += $(EXT_DIR)/librocksdb.a -lrt -lsnappy -llz4 -lz
```

where librocksdb.a is generated by

```
    PORTABLE=1 make static_lib
```

I need to ship the binary to several tens of machines (all are ec2 machines with the same set of packages installed, same code/directory organisation structure).

When I try to run the code however (on the remote machine, not on the local one, where it works fine), I get the following error

```
Error in RockDB: Compression type Snappy is not linked with the binary.
```

When I compile remotely and use the binary from there, it also works fine. Libsnappy is installed on both machines.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this error and generate a binary that can be executed on multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

Use ldd ./yourapplication to check the library dependency on the remote machine.

Or build & install static snappy library before build your application.

I did this on an old machine, it works.